# AWS s3 SignatureDoesNotMatch error during get Request through Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two cloudfront and one s3 bucket and in both cloudfront i have added s3 bucket as a origin. (i am using origin access identity to serve s3 content)
I added same behavior in both cloudfront. 
My problem is 
I am able to access get s3 using only one cloudfront and its throwing error *SignatureDoesNotMatch* with other cloudfront.
For example:
https://cloudront1url/images/a.jpg is working but
https://cloudfront2url/images/a.jpg is not working.

Error that i am getting is [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBL5P.png)

Comment: Are you passing any additional headers from the second one

Comment: No
Request structure of both calls are same

Comment: Something to do with regions. Can you start with S3 regions

Comment: can you share cloudfront 2 setting which you tried. What is setting you added just check with same with cloudfront1

Comment: Also are you sure that you are using static website endpoint instead of S3 bucket endpoint

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got the issue. in behavior i was using "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" (whitelist option) for s3 origin. I was white listing "host" header. when  i choose option "none" in "Cache Based on Selected Request Headers" issue gets resolved.

Comment: This was it for me, ty!

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was Origin Request Policy in Cloudfront being set to `forward all headers` which turns out takes your request headers and calculates signature while s3 calculates signature from specific set of headers.

Correct way to use OAI is with `CORS-S3Origin` request policy or cherry pick selected headers yourself.

Comment: I was thinking it was error from my cloudfront and key signing mechanism, but after looking into deep I come to know its S3 related error  and not my signed cookie code. Setting OAI with CORS-S3Origin fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7):

I got a hint from [this article](https://thecattlecrew.net/2018/10/12/how-to-use-cloudfront-to-serve-private-s3-bucket-as-website/). I had to edit the behavior, use “Legacy cache settings” and select “All” for “Query strings” (select default “None” for “Headers”, and select default “None” for “Cookies”). After that, the `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error was gone.

Here is the screenshot of the CloudFront behavior.
[image: CloudFront behavior editing]